# Socket.io socket.handshake undefined on disconnect

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I have a NodeJS server with socket.io, and have it setup to listen for the `disconnect` event:

```js
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log(socket.handshake); // this works
    console.log(socket.handshake.cookie);

  socket.on('disconnect', function(socket) {
    console.log(socket.handshake); // this does not
    console.log(socket.handshake.cookie);

  });
});
```

In this case, the `'disconnect'` event `socket.handshake` returns undefined, therefore causing a `TypeError: Cannot read property...` etc. The `connection` event logs everything as expected however. Is this because headers aren't passed on disconnect, and if so what information *is* passed?

In essence, my questions are:

1. How come the second pair of `socket.handshake`'s inside the `'disconnect'` event return `undefined`?
2. If this is caused by the `disconnect` event `socket` sending different data, what data *is* sent?
3. Is there any way to get the cookies from the `'disconnect'` event?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove the `socket` argument in that line

```
   socket.on('disconnect', function(socket){
```

Comment: Haha brilliant! I'm _guessing_ the new `socket` passed in the `'disconnect'` event doesn't contain the `handshake` property. But the original from the first `'connection'` event does! So I can use that instead. Thanks a bunch!